# Solving first order PDE: $yz\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} - xz\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = e^z$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm trying to solve this PDE:

$yz\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} - xz\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = e^z$

I have tried method of characteristics:

$\frac{dx}{ds} = yz\\
\frac{dy}{ds} = -xz\\
\frac{dz}{ds} = e^z$

From first two equations I got $x^2 + y^2 = C_1$ and from the third one $z = -ln(c-s)$.
What can I do next to get $C_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that I didnt type it. I send you a photo!
[image]